# Docker Registry: Newly tagged image can be found, but not found when pulled

Tags: docker

Using `:latest` image as a base, I have created a new image tagged with `:v1.1.0-fermium`. After tagging, the newly tagged image `:v1.1.0-fermium` appears within registry listing of docker images, including `:latest`

**Problem:** The `:latest` image can be pulled from registry, but not the newly tagged `:v1.1.0-fermium` image, not found registry.

**Question:** Is there a step I am missing when tagging a docker image in order to be found when pulling from a docker registry?

```
$ docker image tag docker.foo.com/bar-build:latest docker.foo.com/bar-build:v1.1.0-fermium

$ docker image ls docker.foo.com/bar-build

REPOSITORY                            TAG              IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
docker.foo.com/bar-build   latest           35bfeb2c6323   5 hours ago   5.03GB
docker.foo.com/bar-build   v1.1.0-fermium   35bfeb2c6323   5 hours ago   5.03GB

$ docker pull docker.foo.com/bar-build:latest
latest: Pulling from bar-build

$ docker pull docker.foo.com/bar-build:v1.1.0-fermium
Error response from daemon: manifest for docker.foo.com/bar-build:v1.1.0-fermium not found: manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry.
```

Comment: `Is there a step I am missing when tagging a docker image in order to be found when pulling from a docker registry?` Yeah. Pushing.

Comment: Thank you, this worked: `$ docker push docker.foo.com/bar-build:v1.1.0-fermium`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly Push the docker image into hub.docker.com for publishing it and then you can pull the image.